# Load function of a custom model uses incorrect primary key for loading

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.1.7

Inside a custom module, I have created a model for table `teacher_table` having the primary key `teacher_id`.

After instantiating `TeacherTableFactory` class, I tried to load a record by using primary key.

```
$teacherItem = $this->teacherFactory->create();
$teacherItem->load(1);
```

Then, it throws column not found exception. While debugging found out that the load function executes an sql query having where clause on other than primary key column of `teacher_table`.

**Why the load function is using teacher_table_id (generated one) instead of teacher_id (specified in InstallSchema.php)?**

Note: `teacher_table_id` has been used by the load function. There is no such column in `teacher_table`.

Comment: Would you please share your resource model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you specifiy right primary column into resource model

```
<?php
namespace NameSpace\ModelName\Model\ResourceModel;
class ModuelName extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('table_name', 'primary_key');
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be pretty straight forward but i couldn't figure it out by myself. Thanks man.

Comment: welcome :) like it